# Losing connection in Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I'm using a program for inserting data automatically in my Cassandra table.

All is good but after a few moment, I had the following error :

`com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Connection has been closed`

That happens after I insert somethinh like 150 000 rows.

There is the errors in my system.log :

```
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:3] 2017-05-23 10:43:46,415 OutputHandler.java:57 - Error reading row (stacktrace follows):
java.lang.AssertionError: null
at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.Rows.collectStats(Rows.java:70) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter$StatsCollector.applyToRow(BigTableWriter.java:223) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BaseRows.applyOne(BaseRows.java:99) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BaseRows.add(BaseRows.java:89) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.UnfilteredRows.add(UnfilteredRows.java:21) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.Transformation.add(Transformation.java:142) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.Transformation.apply(Transformation.java:108) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.append(BigTableWriter.java:156) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.append(SSTableRewriter.java:129) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.tryAppend(SSTableRewriter.java:153) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.Scrubber.scrub(Scrubber.java:225) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.scrubOne(CompactionManager.java:873) [apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.access$300(CompactionManager.java:81) [apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$3.execute(CompactionManager.java:366) [apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$2.call(CompactionManager.java:314) [apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]`
```

Comment: This is quote a common error and _usually_ (but not always) indicates a problem on the cluster. For example if nodes in the cluster start running long GC pauses then it might not respon in a timely manner and you'll see errors like this at the client. Do you see any errors in your Cassandra `system.log` during the same time window? If so please add them into your question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for adding the log snippet, it probably doesnt show enough information. Could you post the entire log somewhere? Make sure it covers the same period you see the errors.